# ethers SERVER_ERROR that cannot be catched with try/catch

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, nodejs

I am facing strange server error while trying to send eth transaction. It happens not every time and I cannot catch it with try/catch. Is there any known issue?

```
/root/app/node_modules/ethers-new/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:685
            error = new Error(message);
                    ^
Error: server response 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable (request={  }, response={  }, error=null, code=SERVER_ERROR, version=6.7.1)
    at makeError (/root/app/node_modules/ethers-new/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:685:21)
    at assert (/root/app/node_modules/ethers-new/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:702:25)
    at FetchResponse.assertOk (/root/app/node_modules/ethers-new/src.ts/utils/fetch.ts:896:15)
    at JsonRpcProvider._send (/root/app/node_modules/ethers-new/src.ts/providers/provider-jsonrpc.ts:1160:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /root/app/node_modules/ethers-new/src.ts/providers/provider-jsonrpc.ts:500:40 {
  code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
  request: FetchRequest {},
  response: FetchResponse {},
  error: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like RPC provider you are using is not stable. Try using another provider. If possible, infura or quiknode or another provider with ensured SLA